# Apache2 Subdomains www https proxypass

Tags: apache-2.2, https, subdomain, proxypass

I have a quite complicated setup. At least for me, since I'm new to apache, mod_rewrite and all that stuff.

What I want is this:

- remove all www prefixes
- redirect all subdomains to https, and so, excluding the domain itself (foo.bar.com, but not bar.com)
- proxying all requests to subdomains to the port 8089 of the domain

So, I have written a code that mostly works, except for www.foo.bar.com.
I'm now working on a new one.

The thing is, I don't know in which order things would work properly. Should I put get rid of the www first ? Or should I set up the proxying at the top ?

Here's my new file so far.

I hope someone can help me make things clean.

```
# welcome page
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName bar.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/bar
</VirtualHost>

# ssl and proxy for subdomains
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName foo.bar.com
    ServerAlias *.bar.com

    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile    /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key

    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPass / http://bar.com:8089/
    ProxyPassReverse / http://bar.com:8089/

    ProxyVia On
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80 *:443>
    ServerName bar.com
    ServerAlias *.bar.com

    # remove www
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^www\.(.+)              [NC]
    RewriteRule ^               http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301]

    # redirect https://bar.com -> http://bar.com
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS}        on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    ^bar.com$                    [NC]
    RewriteRule ^               http://bar.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

    # redirect http -> https
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS}        off
    RewriteRule (.*)            https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}  [R=301]

    ErrorLog /var/log/foo/foo-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/foo/foo-access.log combined
    LogLevel warn

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>


################
# restrictions #
################

<Location /web/database>
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 1.2.3.4
</Location>
```

Comment: You realize that you can have only one SSL certificate on your Apache server (at least as of 2.2) and therefore, if you have cert for `foo.bar.com`, anyone going to `https://xyz.bar.com` will get an invalid cert as the cert will be for `foo.bar.com`? - That is, unless you have a wildcard certificate. As for the above, does it work? What does not work if anything?

Comment: You have to `ServerAlias` handling the same thing of `*.bar.com` - that won't work or will give you unpredictable results.

Comment: Apache should have warned you that you have overlapping VirtualHosts and that the first takes precedence. Since it does _nothing_...

Comment: @MichaelHampton What do you mean by it does nothing ? This means that I have to write only one or two vhosts (one for each port for exemple), and handle all the work I want to do with mod_rewrite ?